# Why does this CREATE TABLE statement cause "ORA-00922 missing or invalid option"?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have exported a schema from one Oracle database using SQL Developer (tools -> unload database). It has created "create table" statements similar to this one :

```
CREATE TABLE "APP_USER" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "PASSWORD" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(100)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "LIS_DATA" ;
```

But when I try to execute the code on another database, also from SQL Developer, it fires an "ORA-00922 missing or invalid option".

Apparently there is something wrong with the storage section of the query (starting with "SEGMENT" and ending with "DEFAULT)" because if I remove it it works. But what is it exactly ?

I am just an application developer who happens to have to work with Oracle. I'm ok with SQL but this Oracle storage parameters stuff is Chinese to me. Plus I am puzzled that SQL Developer generates invalid code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with "segment creation immediate". It seems to be a 11G feature. Maybe you are trying to create a table using 11G features on an older version database.

Comment: I think you nailed it. The DB I exported from is 11g, I tried to import into 10g. Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

From [HERE](http://ora-00922.ora-code.com/):

> ORA-00922:    missing or invalid option Cause:
>
> An invalid option was
>   specified in defining a column or storage clause. The valid option in
>   specifying a column is NOT NULL to specify that the column cannot
>   contain any NULL values. Only constraints may follow the datatype.
>   Specifying a maximum length on a DATE or LONG datatype also causes
>   this error. Action:   Correct the syntax. Remove the erroneous option or
>   length specification from the column or storage specification.